# Is there a well known algorithm for scattering points uniformly around a central point?

Tags: algorithms

Is there a well known algorithm for scattering points uniformly around a central point?

For example, imagine the pins on Google maps, and imagine you had a data set where two or more points had exactly the same Lat/Long, in order to display both, you would have to nudge at least one of them off the original point.

Comment: Please add any relevant tags.

Comment: Here is a [Wikipedia article "Circle packing in a circle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_circle). Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestand your question, then you want to spread all your dataset around one mean point. For that purpose Gaussian distribution works well for the specified mean and varience.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Comment: It was my pleasure